# MinGW Unicode error

Tags: c++, unicode, mingw

`"english language"` - OK
`"other language"` - OK
`L"english language"` - OK
`L"other language"` - error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte 
                    sequence

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wcout << L"ś" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives that error.

I'm using the newest version of MinGW c++ compiler and I want to make multi-language application and that's the main problem for now.

Comment: Please read the tour carefully on How to ask questions on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/tour , so that we can help you better.

Comment: The problem is from IDE which you are using. Make sure the text/cpp editor is saving the *.cpp file in UTF-8. Printing Unicode in Window console is not simple, specially not with MinGW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my IDE. It was saving source files in bad encoding, changing it to UTF-8 solved it.